# What KalmanEstimator elements tells us?

Tags: filtering, control-systems

I'm looking for an interpretation of Kalman filter in discrete time. You know, if we consider an state space on the form of the form

```
x(k+1) = A.x(k)+ B.u(k)
y(k) = C.x(k) + D.U(k)
```

We can show in Mathematica with the code of

```
sys = StateSpaceModel[{A,B,C,D}, SamplingPeriod->1].
```

Here I use the SamplingPeriod->1 to show that it is a discrete state space system.

this is shown in Mathematica in some shape like

```
A|B

C|D
```

Now, if we apply KalmanEstimator to the above system and write:

`KalmanEstimator[sys,{w,v}]` in which w and v are transition and noise covariance matrices, when we evaluate this expression in mathematica, we again get a system in the following shape

```
A'|B'

C'|D'
```

Now my question is how should we interpret these A',B',C' and D' matrices.
I have done my own research and I know that A' and B' are calculated as:

`x(k+1|k) = (A-gC).x(k|k-1)+   g.y(k)+  (C-gd)` in which g is Kalman gain matrix.

based on above equation, we can see that:

`A'= A-gC & B' = [g  -g]` (I'm now sure about the B' one)

my question is what these C' and D' matrices show to us
you know, in related page of mathematica documentation, it tells that:

"
- The inputs to the Kalman estimator model are the deterministic inputs and the noisy measurements .
- The outputs of the Kalman estimator model consist of the estimated states and estimates of the noisy measurements .
"

but I don't undestand how should I use C' and D' matrices
is there anyone who is familiar with KalmanEstimator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kinds - prediction and current - of Kalman estimators for discrete-time systems. [1]

The state equation is given in the notes section in ref/KalmanEstimator:
[image]

The output equations for the prediction estimator:

$$ \hat{x}(k)=\hat{x}(k)$$
$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \hat{y}_n(k)=c_n.\hat{x}_n(k)+d_{nd}.u_d(k)$$

The output equations for the current estimator:

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \hat{x}(k)=\left(I_n-l.c_n\right).\bar{x}(k)-l.d_{nd}.u_d(k)-l.y_n(k)$$
$$\hat{y}_n(k)=c_n.\hat{x}_n(k)+d_{nd}.u_d(k)$$

You can create these equations from the block diagrams. And the notation is also explained in the notes.

[1] Franklin, Powell, and Workman, Digital Control of Dynamic Systems [[link]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201820544)

Comment: Based on your comment, the first matrix should be an Identity matrix, but it's not!!!

Comment: The 'first matrix' is identity for the prediction estimator. I wrote the state estimate equations $\hat{x}(k)=\hat{x}(k)$ as an afterthought. That is different for the two estimators. Sorry. The output estimator equations are the same.